# NGRX: Unit Test how to mock two different selector

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, ngrx

I been trying to add a mock store inside a component but i am encountered with a problem where the return of my select method inside MockStore class can only return 1 type.  But i need to be able to return either one of them.

**Here is my set up**

**test.spec.ts**

```
class MockStore {
    public select(obj: any): any {
        return of(fruit)
    }
}

beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [
            FormsModule
        ],
        providers: [
            { provide: Store, useClass: MockStore }
        ]
    }).compileComponents()
}))
```

**component.ts**

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.fruit = this.store.select(fruitList)
    this.animal = this.store.select(allAnimals)
}

init(): void {
    const reptile = this.animal.subscribe(animal => {
        animal.filter(a => a.type === 'coldBlood')
    })
}
```

**fruitSelector.ts**

```
// Using NRGX entity pattern
export const selectFruitState = (state): FruitState => state.allFruits
export const fruitList = createSelector(selectFruitState, selectAll)
```

**animalSelector.ts**

```
// using normal create selector pattern
export const selectAnimalState = (state): AnimalState => state.zoo.land
export const allAnimals = createSelector(selectAnimalState, status => status.allAnimals)
```

So the problem is that both of my store have different data structure

```
// Fruit data structure
export const fruit = {
    sweet: sweet.reducer,
    salty: salty.reducer,
    bitter: bitter.reducer
}

// Animal data structure
{
    id: [1, 2, 3],
    enitity: ['monkey', 'elephant', 'snake']
}
```

Changing the data structure will be problematic as i have different structure else where too, I already tried adding Animal data to the MockStore like this

```
class MockStore {
    public select(obj: any): any {
        fruit['animal'] = animal.reducer
        return of(fruit)
    }
}
```

but the problem with this method is that i have an a animal.filter() in init() method which is trying to access Object
this will cause an error. I do not want to change my data structure just because of unit test

Answer (score 1):

Use mockstore in combination with mckselectors - https://ngrx.io/guide/store/testing#using-mock-selectors

```
providers: [
        provideMockStore({
          selectors: [
            { selector: fromBooks.getSearchQuery, value: '' },
            { selector: fromBooks.getSearchResults, value: [] },
            { selector: fromBooks.getSearchLoading, value: false },
            { selector: fromBooks.getSearchError, value: '' },
          ],
        }),
```

More examples can be found in the [example-app](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/tree/master/projects/example-app)

Comment: It only demonstrate how to do it using one store and one type of selector

Comment: @Photonic did you ever figure out how to use multiple stores?

Comment: @timdeschryver in example-app, which file has the unit tests for components that are using the store as a dependency can you please tell me? I couldn't find it.